# Replace array of objects with another in Mongo DB

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, object

I need to replace `members` array data with new array of objects `mems` given below.

```js
{
  "name": "Test Group",
  "members": [{
    'userId': {
      $oid: 'fjkfkffy'
    },
    name: 'Himanshu'
  }],
  "athletes": [],
  "leads": []
}
```

Here I want to replace `members` array of object with new array of objects. I basically need to overwrite that `members` array. I've been trying to do something like this below, but I got an error. Can anyone please help me out?

```js
const mems = [{
    "user": {
      "$oid": "6093a4a709cc0b000d31ber8",
    },
    "role": "manager"
  },
  {
    "user": {
      "$oid": "60a3aea6ecbf4398f01aa598"
    },
    "role": "user"
  }
];
```

```js
entities.findOneAndUpdate({
  _id: ObjectID(entityID),
  "groups._id": ObjectID(groupID)
}, {
  $set: {
    'groups.$.name': name,
    'groups.$.members': mems
  }
}, {
  'new': true
});
```

Comment: can you post what error you are getting?